# SAPUI5: Added index.html and fullWidth attribute in manifest.json is now ignored

Tags: html, sapui5

In the snapshot below you can see the initial layout of an app, run by flpSandbox.

[image: App run with flpSandBox]

In the 2nd snapshot you can see the same app after I added and called an index.html file which I found in a blog and adjusted

[image: App run with index.html]

In order to achieve full width I have already added the following statement in manifest.json:

"sap.ui5": { "config": { "fullWidth": true }, etc etc

Seems that the above parameter is ignored when I call the index.html file, so I tried various ways to define it within index.html itself (HTML below) but without success. Any help?

Regards,

Greg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Agreements Maintenance</title>
      <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
          src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
          data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
          data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
          data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
          data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"kristal.apps.agreements": "../webapp/"}'>
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <script>
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() { 
          new sap.m.Shell({   
              app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                  height : "100%",
                  name : "kristal.apps.agreements"
              })
          }).placeAt("content");
      });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from SDN

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function(){new sap.m.Shell({   

    appWidthLimited:false,

    app:newsap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
        height :"100%",
        name:"kristal.apps.agreements"
    })
}).placeAt("conten...
```